# Is it valid if one licenses their own answer at Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, licensing, creative-commons

I visited CommonsWare's profile and saw this.

[image]

Can one do that? Just curious cos from my understanding all code posted here come under [Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> Can one do that?

They can, but they can't take away any rights that Stack Overflow's CC-Wiki license agreement gives.

The copyright of the content always remains with the author and they can re-license anything they publish on Stack Overflow any way they choose **in parallel** to SO.

I once made an [infographic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123501) illustrating the situation:

[image]

I'm not a lawyer, but I'm fairly sure this means they can apply whatever license or terms they want. To be effective, they just have to be **more** liberal than CC-Wiki.

They can't limit the scope of CC-Wiki willy nilly - or rather, they can, but you can simply ignore it in favour of the CC-Wiki license, to which they have agreed in full the moment they posted the content on SO.

There is, of course, the fact that they don't *publish* the content in parallel in a place different from SO. They just declare that a different kind of license applies to the content posted here.

I guess in theory, Stack Overflow could try and prohibit that, arguing that it's content published on their platform according to their terms. But I can't see why they would ever want to do that, unless they suddenly turned very, very evil - for which there aren't any signs at the moment, imo.

Comment: They can offer less liberal licenses too, but the CC-Wiki license cannot be revoked or negated. You'd just ignore the less liberal license because you can just stick with CC-Wiki instead.

Comment: @Martin exactly, yeah, that's putting it much better than I did.

Comment: Are those freehand drawn circles?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Did you draw that lovely picture :D?

Comment: @Rizier123 I did! Using highly scientific means, of course. Yes, those are freehand circles.

Comment: wow, very nice infographics. made me remember the quote, "maturity is not losing the child in you" :)

Comment: What happened to the big "nothing to do with SO" bubble?

Comment: @AlexisKing you have sharp eyes (and a good memory)! That one is [here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123501/by-posting-a-selection-of-previously-written-text-here-are-we-waiving-our-copyr/123507#123507)

Comment: does this mean i could license my text under something which permits unrestricted replication *even without attribution*, thereby undermining SO's requirement for attribution?

Comment: @Woodrow sure - although for it to be totally watertight, I guess you'd have to publish the same content *somewhere else* and specify the more liberal license there. The argument could be made that by publishing on SO, you're implicitly agreeing to their terms and conditions, and you can't invalidate one of its clauses willy nilly. However, I've seen many SO users do exactly that, and it seems very unlikely that Stack Exchange, Inc. would ever contest this.

Comment: Why are the words "̱a̱ṉḏ Stack Overflow" not anti-aliased? It looks like they were added later, to a drawing that wasn't about SO to begin with, but the rest of the drawing ***is*** about SO, so that's not it.

Answer (score 59):

Yes, one can do that. They are giving you an *additional license*, so you can pick whatever license fits your needs. Since they are the original author of the content, they have the right to offer that content to you under any license they see fit.

The author is effectively giving you a [multiple licenses to choose from](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing).

Note that any re-use and reworking of the content under the CC-Wiki license is not covered under the additional licenses; if I take CommonsWare's work and add to it or alter it, give him attribution under the terms of the CC-Wiki license, then that is a *collective work* and not his work to license, so only CC-Wiki then applies.

Comment: This is beautiful in its brevity. Says all that is needed and should be the top answer. I admit I posted my answer mostly for an excuse to embed the infographic again :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 It *is* a very nice infographic. Look at how cheerful that guy is!

Comment: @Pekka웃: damn, foiled by your superior infographics skilz again! That is a *nice* infographic.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. may i ask why we are not using more liberal licenses? to legally protect against plagiarism / site scraping? (is it a dumb assumption? ) :)

Comment: @naveen: found it, see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/): *it’s a way of guaranteeing that we can’t ever do anything nefarious with the questions and answers the community have so generously shared with us.*

Comment: @naveen: also of course, Stack Overflow content is not *only* code, and the Stack Exchange network does not only cover programming subjects, so liberal code licenses may not make much sense here or elsewhere on the SE network.

Answer (score 1):

On the surface this looks a bit dodgy, but in reality every single user on stackoverflow should put a similar clause in their profile. This explicitly licences your code snippet for free use by people who see it, which Creative Commons doesn't apparently.

Comment: "which Creative Commons doesn't apparently" -- it is more that CC licenses are great for prose but lousy for code, particularly when you inevitably try combining that code with other code.