# Streaming Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, rules

There are communities of people who watch other people program (e.g. [Twitch](http://www.twitch.tv/)).

Imagine one would ask and answer questions or do review queues on a live stream.
This could bring a lot of attention to those questions (think meta-effect, just bigger), but there may be other dangers I did not think of.

Would that be totally fine as it makes Stack Overflow more popular?
Would it be cheating? Can one get banned?

Issues that arise from showing Stack Overflow on stream:

- Copyright / Giving attribution

  - It is unclear if showing the question, URL and user names counts as giving attribution.
  - It is unclear if attribution with a hyperlink is even feasible for a stream/video.
  - It is unclear if linking questions and answers in the stream chat is sufficient, because the chat is not always recorded, does not appear in the past broadcasts and may be too separated from the video.
- Disclosure

  - Viewers get to see Stack Overflow at the streamer's rep level, not their own.

    - Number of up- and downvotes
    - Deleted questions and answers
    - Review queues

    Assuming there is a reason for the rep requirements they may not serve their purpose in this situation.
  - If the streamer does not pay attention information may be disclosure from the streamer's personal page.
- Meta effect

  - Exposed questions and answers may attract an unusual amount of attention. It is unclear if this is a problem or a bonus.

Comment: You may need to be careful about anything that would show your profile, since that may inadvertently expose personally identifying information that only you would normally see.

Comment: I assume the 'cheating' question surrounds the possibility of Twitch viewers helping the streamer answer questions? I don't see anything wrong with that. If it's their prerogative to help the streamer rather than make their own account, so be it.

Comment: Seems like this would be no different than making use of the "Share" link. In fact, i'd suggest pairing this... streaming... with the use of the Share link to maximize the effect.

Comment: I am imagining the meta effect being applied by a less-informed mob.

Comment: @TylerH That is the Reddit effect, and it doesn't really need to be imagined; it happens often enough already.

Comment: Wouldn't CC-BY-SA require the broadcaster to provide attribution for every post whose content appears on such a live stream?

Comment: This is already happening on livecoding.tv

Comment: I want to see Jon Skeet stream :).

Comment: Seems like a transformative work to me, as the performance aspect is far more significant than the questions...

Comment: If you use it as an informative channel and avoid the personal portions of the site (your profile information) I doubt there is anything you can have come back. You would essentially use it as a training tool to describe best tactics of review queues, visually how to create an answer and get it to be the best you can make it. Hopefully you're good at these things. If you're not.. well maybe it will be fun to watch you get better.

Comment: @CodeCaster Maybe you could give it a shot! Your name is already perfect. :)

Comment: @Jashaszun:  Maybe if he were streaming how he'd test NodaTime or build a few microservices.  Surely those would be infinitely more entertaining to watch than to see him answer questions, and get upvotes *because he's Jon Skeet.*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Wouldn't just the URL of the page shown in the livestreamer's browser be sufficient attribution? Not to mention the OP's username shown on the page itself.

Comment: @Ajedi32 you would have to include attribution for each post shown and its owner. So if you scrolled to the bottom of a page with 5 answers on it then your would have to attribute 6 posts (including the question) and users before you start typing an answer.

Comment: [I suggested this a while back](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270584/302677) on a semi-related question. Based on some of the responses, there was some interest in watching other coders if you were good enough, but you may want to read through the comment thread to see some of the concerns :)

Comment: @TinyGiant My point is, scrolling to the bottom of the page wouldn't just make the text of the answers visible, but also the username's of the original posters, and the name and url of the site you're on. That's probably sufficient attribution IMO.

Comment: But it isn't, the guidelines state that you have to *link* to the post being attributed, not just show the name. What if the name changes? The link will still redirect to the correct user but the old user name will not help when searching for the creator.

Comment: @Ajedi, you have nailed it. The problem is not with the original poster's nickname, but with the URL behind it. Prominently displaying the nickname (which is not a given in a video streaming situation and will require special care) as well as hyperlinks to both the post and the user profile (possibly actionable, if you can do that) would be a must I believe.

Comment: Please note that anything not music, game or game talkshow related is afaik against the TOS of twitch. A friend showed me a site called livecoding, which is... people streaming them coding something, but I don't think reviewing questions on stackoverflow is within their scope. I am also not sure how interesting it is to watch someone else do a review task.

Comment: I wonder nobody has mentioned the [exciting and absolutely thrilling] [Stack Overflow Rap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9z30ulAizU). (Should this guy be sued as well?)

Comment: @Sumurai8 They have a dedicated [category for programming](http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Programming). I thought of SO more of a filler for downtime, not the main event. Also not every community is so off-topic -> close happy.

Comment: I know that an anime talk show was rejected by twitch admins, and thus moved to a different platform. If a stream does not attract much attention, you can do pretty much anything, but as soon as it attracts attention that changes things a lot on twitch. If there is a category for programming that should not be a real problem.

Answer (score 9):

At the bottom of most / all Stack Exchange pages, you can find [this link](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), which says they "require" links to the post and authors (among other things, which should be covered), which you won't get automatically with a stream.

On the other hand, the above post also says "as long as a good faith effort is made to attribute the content", presumably meaning these rules aren't enforced with an iron fist, but rather something to fall back on if they feel you're not providing fair attribution.

So:

- A straight-forward stream with no additional information is, strictly speaking, disallowed.

  Although, considering the good faith clause, it's not unreasonable to assume showing the URL bar in the stream would make it fine.
- If you provide a link to each question you visited and links to each author whose content appeared on your screen at any point, you seem to be clearly in the green.

  As mentioned in the comments, you could always just write a Chrome extension or user script or something that shows the links to the authors' profiles somewhere on the screen.

I am not a lawyer and don't represent Stack Exchange - perhaps they want clickable links (perhaps because not all that many people type URLs in manually all that often, making image- or video-based attribution much less useful), which would presumably be a lot harder to conform to.

---

The above is of course based on the assumption that the attribution clause in the licence allows Stack Exchange to dictate what acceptable attribution of their content is - I have no idea whether this is true or not. If it isn't, I'm sure you can make a decent case for whatever (although you may find yourself banned from the site if they think you're not attributing fairly).

Comment: If this is true then you could sue a lot of people. It feels like this is not intended.

Comment: @nwp, you couldn't necessarily sue people directly. You can report someone to stack exchange for plagiarism, and they will handle it, but I don't think that you get to sue anyone for it.

Comment: @nwp Sue which people? If anyone shares any content from anywhere without conforming to the rules specified by the licence under which it was shared, they open themselves up to legal action against them. But there's also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/what-is-up-with-the-source-code-license-on-stack-overflow/25957#25957), which I roughly understand as: it's probably okay to use bits of code found on Stack Overflow as part of a larger project without attribution - the idea, I imagine, is more to avoid Stack Overflow clones and direct copies of full answers.

Comment: @TinyGiant AFAIK you just grant SE a licence, you don't give up ownership, thus you could sue people (including SE) if they don't conform to any licence under which it was licensed under. [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291319/is-it-valid-if-one-licenses-their-own-answer-at-stack-overflow).

Comment: If this is a really an actual problem (which I doubt) you could always just write a Chrome extension or user script or something that shows the links to the posts and author's profiles at the top of every post, then do your streaming with that extension enabled.

Comment: If you're going to be streaming the SO website though, that's your attribution right there, yes?

Comment: @Dukeling: [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) does not require to *link* the URI. The attribution can be done in ways "reasonable to the medium or means You are utilizing", and providing the URI is required "to the extent reasonably practicable". The additional restrictions outlined in the SE blog post "Attribution Required" (which, btw., [misses an important requirement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225486/193139)) are not enforceable.

Comment: What? if streaming a video of using SO (address bar, and full page) doesn't count as attribution for the Q&As, then SO is also not using proper attribution since that's exactly what it shows you when you visit the page. This is silly. The only difference between watching someone use SO and using it yourself is the lack of clicky links.... but you can just go to the page via the posted URL and find them. And attribution only requires a name and (preferably) location, not a clickable hyperlink.

Comment: @slicedtoad This answer analyzes different points of view and comes to the conclusion that it's probably fine (as long as you include the URL bar, otherwise finding one's way to the question becomes a lot more effort). To ignore other points of view would be silly.

Comment: @unor Stack Exchange is not using the CC license directly, they are using it augmented by the terms of that blog post. Everywhere that the CC license is referenced, the terms of that blog post are also referenced; so it's enforceable as it's part of the implicitly combined licensing agreement for the site. Possibly. Maybe. Licensing in all respects has never been handled entirely clearly by SEI. Still, I agree that including the address bar should definitely be considered a "good faith" attribution, as vaguely specified in Jeff's post-which-really-could-have-benefited-from-a-lawyer-bleh.

Comment: @Dukeling *\*Sigh\**. That post is absurdly ridiculous and should really be deleted. Jeff asserted a blatantly incorrect legal interpretation (the Creatives Commons licenses are not sufficiently legally similar to software licenses for them to satisfy its terms), and then mocked users who understand the situation better than he does for legitimate and correct concerns. *"It's not a license mess, some people are a mess."* Nope. He created a massive licensing mess, defensive denied it, and the situation is unresolved seven years later. 

Comment: @JeremyBanks welly welly well look who's a *legal expert now!* I'm pretty sure a good faith effort to include the major question links you covered in the video should suffice. Like in the YouTube (sorry, I don't use this new fangled "Twitch" thing) video description, just link the main bits there. This is of nice in a "show notes" capacity anyway since many people probably don't want to sit through a 30 minute video to painstakingly suss out which question URLs are involved.

Answer (score 4):

It is very difficult to ascertain IP (Intellectual Property) in this case. In legal terms there is the case of what *should be* and what *can actually be*.

There have been multiple run-ins on this front, the main one I remember was about 6-8 years ago (can't quite remember) when YouTube began banning and deleting videos which contained game footage not distributed by the game's publisher (this was, of course, eventually overturned; essentially deemed "stupid").

The reason why this is such a grey area is because of what you are filming (streaming). In most cases you are streaming your own computer, Windows/Mac/Linux/What-ever and in this case it is difficult to attribute IP breach since you are basically streaming your life. It isn't technically a reproduction or reuse of sorts. It is merely foreground to the stream.

It is like saying that because someones poster was in the background of your photo that you owe them IP, or even that you owe IP to the authority of whose ground you took the photo on. It just does not work in a legal sense, it is one of those times where common sense overrules technicalities.

In fact, recently the EU wanted to pass a bill on this very nature. They wanted to make photographers ascertain IP from all the building owners before taking a photo shot. Can you imagine standing in the middle of London and taking a photo? You would have to get IP from 100's of people, this was eventually seen as completely unreasonable and unpractical in a legal sense, in other words common sense eventually won.

Due to the absurdly grey area that is this it is normally just good enough to mention somewhere that you're using StackOverflow when streaming. For example, use of other clips (films etc) normally requires attribution on a parent level but you wouldn't normally attribute every actor unless you was reviewing the film.

In terms of disclosure, that is down to the individual, if they show sensitive information then that's on them. I personally do not consider the rep count nor votes etc to be sensitive, let the whole world see frankly. What is sensitive is the little things like my email address and real name. Fortunately all these are hidden unless you go to edit your profile. So it seems most of the profile is streamable so long as you don't mind displaying yourself to the world, if not then why are you streaming?

The Meta effect is a problem I cannot see an easy solution around.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific rule that bans this behavior.
So this is perfectly fine, if you [provide attribution](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

I am not a lawyer and I do not represent Stack Exchange, but I think that seeing the logo and the page link in the URL bar along with each author's usercard will be enough.

Anyway, consider the following:

- You may want to hide any personal information while recording, like you'd do if you used a public PC.
- You may get help from your fellow viewers, like you'd do if you were at work.
- Although many uninformed people would reach the site, they would just view the pages without giving any feedback, like [they already do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297527/3453226).

Comment: [They seem to "require" links](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), which you won't get automatically with a stream. Only SE would be able to give a definitive answer here, although as it stands, it seems to be disallowed.

Comment: @Dukeling Added in the answer.

Comment: *However, they can see the logo in the video. I think this will be enough.* I don't think so, no. Our license requires more extensive attribution.

Comment: @Dukeling That same post also says "This is about the spirit of fair attribution. Attribution to the website, and more importantly, to the individuals who so generously contributed their time to create that content in the first place!" I think in a video format, the website and usernames of the users involved being displayed in the video should be enough. Assuming of course that we're going by the "spirit" of the license here, not the letter. It's pretty clear Jeff had web content in mind when he wrote that post, not livestreaming.

Comment: Another relevant quote: "feel free to remix and reuse to your heart's content, as long as a good faith effort is made to attribute the content!" In the context of a livestream, I believe "good faith effort" doesn't necessarily require making the links to every user's profile visible. Just the URL of the question, the poster's username, and the context making it clear that you're browsing StackOverflow would likely be sufficient.

Comment: @Dukeling: As noted in other meta posts, a blog post about one party's interpretation of contract terms does not bind the other party. Even more, copyright law has no problem with conversions to different media which may have different technical constraints. Even if you did include the blog contents in a contract, you'd still need to address what "hyperlinks" mean for non-hyperlinked media.