# Code with license in comments not compatible with CC BY-SA?

Tags: discussion, licensing

I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22107996/1717300), which includes an explicit license in the code. While I am not certain, the license seems to make the code not license-able as CC BY-SA, by explicitly forbidding uses which CC BY-SA would allow. Yet the code seems to be posted by the copyright holder himself.

**Do I understand CC BY-SA correctly, for this particular answer?**

**More generally, what is correct response from high-rep user when stumbling upon content, which would *appear* (IANAL) to have this kind of a licensing problem?**

I left comment for the poster, who seems to still be active on the site. Should a moderator flag be raised? Or just leave it there, let it be between the poster and whoever would use the code under CC BY-SA but against the license stated in the post (because most likely there will never be any confrontation)?

(Note: That is an old question, and this meta post isn't about quality or other merits of it or its answers, please.)

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291319/is-it-valid-if-one-licenses-their-own-answer-at-stack-overflow) is a proposed duplicate, but it is about user's profile page license clauses, and does not answer what to *do* with *answers* which have explicitly different license in the answer text. The answer to this question might be "ignore" or "downvote if you think answer with such license not useful, then move on" or "raise moderator flag" or what ever, but it is not given there.

Comment: Stating an explicit license in an answer will probably override the implicitly granted licence due to the SO ToS (or amend it, if it is not stated that it's the only license) under most legislations. When the licence is as visible as in the post this is no such big problem, as the readers immediately see how the code is licensed. Such a license is not in the sense of the ToS, which means it may deserver a down vote, but the alternative would be that people post their non-CC code in a pastebin and only link it, which means the link rot will kill their answer (or question) after some time.

Comment: Very relevant: [A New Code License: The MIT, this time with Attribution Required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956) on Meta.SE.

Comment: @hyde:  I'm actually seeing that as a valid answer to this question - "You have to be more liberal than CC-by-SA when relicensing, and it's likely that the more restrictive license is ignored because all questions/answers posted are licensed through CC-by-SA."

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, that's been my starting assumption. It still doesn't discuss how to handle such answer, into which I am seeking some more insight here.

Comment: When it comes to licensing, "handle" implies that there's a legal matter afoot.  AFAIK there's no litigation on who owns that particular snippet of code active, nor has there been a DMCA request to take it down based on that fact.  Editing the answer isn't beneficial since there's really no *harm* to having that text there; it just becomes a matter for lawyers if it's replicated and copied verbatim.  Y'know, kind of how it always has been.

Comment: @Makoto How I, as a user, "handle" it doesn't involve any legalities. Well, my answer: I'll refrain from flagging, which was the main thing I wanted to know, and probably also from commenting if I encounter similar answers in future, only downvoting if I deem the answer as not very useful due to confusing/distracting license clutter.

Answer (score -3):

This just means [dual licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing). Anybody who wants to use the code can choose any of the licenses.

PD: this is only true if the author of the code is the same person who wrote the answer. If the code was just copied, then they had no right to post that code in Stack Overflow in the first place. However, that answer says that they wrote the code ("an early draft that's included in an opengl library that I'm cooking up"), so this doesn't apply here.