# What should I do when there is a license text in code from an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, ethics, licensing

I came across an answer from a question in the bounty section and upvoted the answer, because it makes more sense and looks helpful than the other ones, but this answer had a complete MIT license text in it. It is looked unnecessary to me.

The answer looked like this:

[image]

I made a comment and kindly asked the OP to remove the license text from the answer, but I got this reply:

[image]

At this point I realized OP wasn't going to fix it and to prevent this from happening again, I edited the answer and removed the licencing text. I also told OP to refrain from posting the license text from his future questions and got this reply:

[image]

I am getting accused of "breaking the law" and not "respecting his rights". Now, OP removed the code from the answer and linked to a GitHub page. At least, the license text is now gone.

Should we ignore the license texts in posts?

What should I have done?

*I do think the OP should provide the part of the code relevant to the question, link to the complete code to the GitHub page then mention that the code is under a MIT license instead of posting a complete MIT license text. I wonder what every answer would be like if they include the license texts*

Comment: Related but not an answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291319/is-it-valid-if-one-licenses-their-own-answer-at-stack-overflow/291322#291322

Comment: You can slap a comment on there about him having dual-licensed the code as CC BY SA by posting it on Stack Overflow, and that you have every right to scrap the license since the code is still attributed to him and still under the CC BY SA license as indicated by the page footer, but I imagine you've already made a similar claim and he didn't respond well.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yes, I left the part that says the code is under "MIT license" license in my EDIT and just removed the big license text but this user not happy.

Comment: I know this was asked and it was said that while the author has every right to duel license their code, they don't have the right to use SO as the platform to publish their code in other licenses, and that it should be removed from posts as noise.  I can't find the dupe though.  Including the license and stating it applies to your contributions is fine in the profile though, as per my earlier link.

Comment: @Servy I told this user he doesn't need to contribute or publish his code if he has another license. That's why he removed his code.

Comment: @Servy Is this the one you're looking for: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291995/do-stack-exchange-sites-allow-to-include-copyright-license-in-code-snippets ? it is on MSE so can't be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @rene Looks like it to me.

Comment: @Programmer:  Sounds like the consensus is (after reading the cross-site dupe) is to remove the license and flag for moderator attention if they roll it back once more.

Comment: I will notify the mod if it is rolled back.

Comment: Side note: If the answer is now just a link to a repo, flag it as NAA.

Comment: Please include quoted material **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text.

Comment: @NicHartley He removed the code from the answer and just made it bunch of texts describing the code he linked. A mod re-added the code back, OP rolled it back again due to his "licensing rights" then the answer was down-voted. He deleted the answer, created a new one with similar texts, it got down-voted, OP deleted that one. So far everything is looking fine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I used screenshot because I didn't want the  meta effect to kick in. Wanted to make it harder to find the post but will use text version in the future.

Comment: That's quite a definition of fine. ;)

Comment: Doesn't the MIT license **remove** the attribution requirement?

Comment: @KevinWorkman: No, the MIT license pretty much makes attribution the only requirement.

Answer (score 57):

There's a lot of confusion here, and it's causing far more problems than are necessary.

Disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer. Don't interpret this as legal advice.

1. If *you are the sole author* of something, you can license it however you want. You can have one license, or two licenses, or multiple licenses - the folks using it can then choose whichever license they wish to use.
2. If you're posting code *here*, then you must agree to license it under [the CC-BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). **This doesn't preclude you from *also* offering it under other licenses** - if you have the authority to set one license, then you can also set however many other licenses.

Lots of folks go out of their way to specify that they're dual-licensing the code they post on Stack Overflow. For instance, [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160466/artofcode?tab=profile). And that's fine.

What we need to ensure here is that the author of that answer understands that putting an MIT license on their code *does not* strip the CC-BY-SA license; it only adds another license to the pile. Also, that posting here (with or without a license) never puts it in the public domain by default; if they're the author, then they retain full rights to it, with the caveat that by posting they're agreeing to license it to both Stack Overflow and any readers under the terms of CC-BY-SA. If they're ok with that, then they can put an MIT header in, or whatever. If they're not ok with that, then they shouldn't post the code here - hosting it on GitHub is actually preferable, *as long as the answer stands on its own.*

See also:

- [Subscriber Content Licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) in the Terms of Service
- [Licencing code snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/licencing-code-snippets)

Comment: This guy has just realised he should probably re-word that sentence a touch...

Comment: So you're saying, it's ok for the author to include the license and that it should not be edited out? But it doesn't prevent it being available under the CC-BY-SA license of course.

Comment: I really don't care that much, @YvetteColomb. I'm mostly bothered by the poor communication here: it'd have been more useful to ascertain whether the author was aware of how the default licensing works here, whether they even owned the code they were posting, etc... And then, once everyone was on the same page, we could've tried to work with them. As it was, we had folks talking past each other in the comments and an edit-war, and nothing of value to anyone came out of it.

Comment: @Shog9: Not just the author, but everyone else for that matter. Talking about stripping the alternate license from the answer as if dual licensing wasn't allowed (or wasn't a thing)? Calling license notices "noise"?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Since the code already implicitly has a license due to being posted here, mentioning *another* license is at best a minor tangential detail that has little to no relevance for the vast majority of people. I'd say they *can* include it, as long as it doesn't take up more than *one* line in a post (e.g. mention the license and include a link to give more details).

Comment: @Dukeling it might be a good case of licensed under <license name> with <link to more details>. A case for encouraging links.

Comment: @BoltClock License notices *are* noise unless there's actually a reason to dual-license the code in question. For most code snippets on Stack Overflow, there isn't - because most code snippets are either sufficiently trivial (e.g. single API calls) that there's no way you could win a copyright suit over their use anyway, or are examples that you wouldn't want to copy and paste as-is. There's no link to the question that sparked this argument, as far as I can see, but it looks like it was a toy example of a design pattern, with toy identifier names? Nobody would copy such a thing.

Comment: You successfully increased ArtOfCode's profile page view count by 1k!